# I don't get the concept of findIndex()

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```js
const array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];

const isLargeNumber = (element) => element > 13;

console.log(array1.findIndex(isLargeNumber));
// expected output: 3
```

I don't get this output.
Why 3? There are only 2 of it. Isn't it?

Comment: [The findIndex() method returns the index of the first element in an array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no elements satisfy the testing function, -1 is returned.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) 130 is the first at index 3.

Comment: The first encounter of a number greater than 13 is on index '3',

Comment: Because findIndex return the index of first match

Comment: `Array#findIndex` gets the index of the first element of an array that matches the condition (`isLargeNumber`). the number `130` is the first number that meets the condition. It is at position 4, which is index 3. Indexes start at 0

Comment: "index" !== "count"

Comment: Actually, if you have an array of numbers, strings, etc., it's better to use `.indexOf`. But if you have an array of objects, use `.findIndex` with a callback and determine which object matches the criteria.

Comment: @A1exandrBelan it's not possible to use `.indexOf()` here. Not unless you already know which item meets the criteria, which means you need at least two traversals - one to find the item that fulfils the predicate, the second is the call to `.indexOf()` to find its position in the array. Which `.findIndex()` compresses into one traversal.

Comment: Okay I'm sooo dumb wahaha I think I should read docs carefully and precisely.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

The [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method returns the index of the first element in an array that satisfies the provided testing function.

The output is 3 since the first element that is greater than 13 is 130.

> ```
> 5, 12, 8, 130, 44
> 0  1   2  3    4
> ```

The output is the index of the first element that satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 1):

As the function definition says: "The findIndex() method returns the index of **the first element in an array that satisfies the provided testing function**. If no elements satisfy the testing function, -1 is returned."

So your case will return 3, because 130 is the first value encountered which is bigger than 13, and it's at the third position, because arrays start from zero!

Answer (score 1):

The findIndex() method returns the index (position) of the first element that passes a test. Hence output 3 is correct. number 130 at index 3 is the first element to pass test of ( element > 13 )

Answer (score 0):

There might be two large numbers, but [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) doesn't *count* all entries that pass the truth test. It returns the index of the *first element's index* to pass it. Consider this:

```js
const array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];
const isLargeNumber = function(element, index) {
    console.log('index:', index, 'element:', element, element > 13 ? 'Found. End.' : 'Not found. Continue')
    return element > 13
}

console.log(array1.findIndex(isLargeNumber));
// expected output: 3
```

It logs the following:

- index: 0 element: 5 Not found. Continue
- index: 1 element: 12 Not found. Continue
- index: 2 element: 8 Not found. Continue
- **index: 3 element: 130 Found. End.** → Therefore, the result is 3

Comment: How many more answers that answers the same we need?

Comment: My answer is the only one with a log. Let the question owner decide what they find most helpful and comprehensable.

Comment: @shaedrich a log doesn't fundamentally change the information. All answers state that the first found element is found. Which is also what the documentation states. Adding a log doesn't really make it any different, just restates the same information that's already there.

Comment: I would see it as visualizing rather than simple restating. For us, the behavior of the function might be obvious but it might not be for beginners.

Comment: I agree with shaedrich on this one. The example of the OP is copied from the docs, which means the OP does not comprehend those docs.

Comment: @JavaScript Good observation! I didn't catch that when I copied the link to the docs

Answer (score 0):

**lets look this an example**

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
const array1 = [1,3,4,7,14]
const array2 = [120, 100, 5, 9]

const fun =(ar)=>{
const getIndex = ar.findIndex((e)=> e > 13)
return getIndex;
}
console.log(fun(array)) // this checks iteration from 0 to array.length so here its not found then we got -1 
console.log(fun(array1)) // this case we got index at 4 because it has looped from index 0 to end and it did't found any element from index 0 to index 3
console.log(fun(array2)) // here element is looped and get found at first iteration then it gives the first matched value index 0
```